# How to pass a string with an apostrophe as a header to a node server with a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'll simplify this question here as best as I can:

First on the client side:

```
let textToSend = "Shouldn't it work";
console.log(textToSend) // Logs: Shouldn't it work (with apostrophe)

let response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/somewhere",{
   method:"POST",
   headers:{
         "message" : textToSend
        }
})
```

Then on the server:

```
exports.function = function(req,res){
   let messageText = req.get("message");
   console.log(messageText); //Logs: Shouldn
}
```

So pretty much my problem is, the string gets cut to "Shouldn" since there's an apostrophe after the n.
I've tried adding a backslash before the apostrophe but still does the same thing  Any ideas? I've also tried a double backslash.

Also, in the PostgreSQL server it's connected to, the datatype is varchar.

Comment: Have you tested URI-encoding the text before sending it?

Comment: I remember replacing the apostrophe with &rsquo; but it would just log $rsquo; so it didn't seem to work 

Comment: I don't think that's URI encoding. Looks like HTML entities to me instead.

Comment: When I try to use textToSend.indexOf("'") it returns -1 which is weird too thought that was how to search for apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some more research on URI encoding, I found that decoding does not work on node for some reason . However, when fetching the results, the encoded text can be decoded on the client side when needed, example:

Client Side:

```
let textToSend = encodeURI("Shouldn't it work");
console.log(textToSend); //Logs: Shouldn%E2%80%99t%20it%20work

let response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/somewhere",{
   method:"POST",
   headers:{
         //lets send this message to the server
         "message" : textToSend
        }
})
```

Server Side:

```
let message = req.get("message");
console.log(decodeURI(message)); //Logs: Shouldn%E2%80%99t%20it%20work
//Notice how decoding doesn't work here for some reason
```

Back on client side:

```
let response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/getMessages",{
   method:"GET",
})
if(response.ok){
   try{
     let json = await response.json();
     console.log(decodeURI(json)); //Logs: Shouldn't it work
   }catch(e){
     console.log(e)
   }
}
```

In summary, encode it when sending, decode it when receiving it, don't decode it on the server side.